# Issue while Copying table on PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, copy

```
`aksessuar_up`

id (auto increment)    model     model_id
50                       15          100
51                       17          102
52                       19          105
53                       15          106

`users_projects`

id (auto increment)    model
10                       5
11                       7
12                       9
13                       1
```

I want to copy table `aksessuar_up` to table `users_projects_aks`. While copying I just want to copy `users_projects(id)` to `users_projects_aks(model_id)`. The query below does not work correctly, I tried use INNER JOIN and CROSS JOIN, but haven't got any result.

```
INSERT INTO
  users_projects_aks (model, model_id)
SELECT
  au.model, up.id
FROM
 aksessuar_up as au,
 users_projects as up;
```

I want to get this result after copying:

```
`users_projects_aks`

id (auto increment)    model     model_id
1                       15          10
2                       17          11
3                       19          12
4                       15          13
```

You can see `model_id` is suitable to `users_projects(id)`

Comment: What result are you getting and on which column you want to join

Comment: I can see that there would be no results when performing a 'basic' join, there are no matching values between the two tables so there would be nothing to join.

Comment: Take a look here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3057/1 I have added an extra row to teh tables aksessuar_up and users_projects to show you the results.

Comment: ok, let me check. Thank you for answer

Comment: ON au.model=up.model - It does not work.

Comment: Guess I misunderstood, take a look at this then: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a59b/1 With this one it's okay if there are no matching keys.

Comment: Now your new sql inserts 16 element. But it has to be 3. Right now there are 3 model and 3 model_id. But it inserted 16.

Comment: Then you really need a matching column in order to find the rows that should join. For example you could join on aksessuar_up.model = users_projects.model like in the first example i gave you. sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3057/1

Comment: The oproblem was solved. ))